# cl.exe Failed with exit code 2 while building pyzmq ERROR: Couldn't build wheels for pyzmq, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: pip, cl, cl.exe

What I'm doing here is trying to install mitosheet and build & link required dependencies for jupyter such that I'm able to export notebook.ipynb or other files as pdf.

When I'm running (**python3 -m pip install pyzmq --no-binary pyzmq**) to install pyzmq ignoring wheels, it successfully builds wheels for pyzmq.

```
C:\Users\SHARV> **python3 -m pip install pyzmq --no-binary pyzmq**
*Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable*

Collecting pyzmq
Downloading pyzmq-25.1.2.tar.gz (1.4 MB)
 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 
1.4/1.4 MB 3.1 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Installing build dependencies ... done
Getting requirements to build wheel ... done

Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done

Building wheels for collected packages: pyzmq
Building wheel for pyzmq (pyproject.toml) ... done

Created wheel for pyzmq: filename=pyzmq-25.1.2-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl size=672485 sha256=6d778259a71e1a4bef8e32a98a63cbd82977e27fbbb8b97afaebb5041aae648d

Stored in directory: c:\users\sharv\appdata\local\pip\cache\wheels\b1\52\ef\086c3aa0c7f61df6c214d61fe7dad829198444748224f2603b

Successfully built pyzmq

Installing collected packages: pyzmq

Successfully installed pyzmq-25.1.2
```

but it failes with **python -m pip install mitosheet**

```
C:\Users\SHARV> **python -m pip install mitosheet**
C:\\Program Files\\Python312\\include\\cpython/longintrepr.h(87): note: see declaration of '\_longobject'DEBUG EXT_SUFFIX '.cp312-win_amd64' '.cp312-win_amd64.pyd'
 \*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\
 \*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*
DEBUG EXT_SUFFIX '.cp312-win_amd64' '.cp312-win_amd64.pyd'
\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\
\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.39.33519\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
\[end of output\]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyzmq
Failed to build pyzmq

ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyzmq, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
C:\\Users\\SHARV\>
```

All paths are present in system Environment variable.
[Environment Variables] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/flRAv.png)

I've checked with both Visual studio 2019 and Visual studio 2022. cl.exe is present.
[Developer Command Prompt Visual Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPnMh.png)

In my understanding, I've installed and configured the requirements needed to build wheel for pyzmq. I'm unable to figure out why there's still a problem from a subprocess.

,
PYTHON VERSION IS 3.12
NBCONVERT is updated as of now.
pandoc is also installed.
Xelatex is present from MikTex.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I've Clarified the problem now.